# Cordova Plugin Camera Mediatype with Video is not working

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, video, cordova-plugins

i am working on a Cordova ionic App with angularjs. I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) for the camera function. I am trying to set the camera for pictures and videos but the **problem is**:  i can only take picture. The Videocamera is not working. I tried it on 2 Samsung devices (Tablet and Phone).

This is my Code: (AngularJS)

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ionic"]);

var controllerApp = function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Its Works !";

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log(navigator.camera);
    }

    $scope.getPic = function () {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 25,
            mediaType: Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,                
        });

        function onSuccess(imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }

        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }
    }
};
        app.controller("controllerApp", ["$scope", controllerApp]);
```

HTML

```
<div class="col col-40" ng-model="excercise.excerciseMedia">Set Media</div>
<button class="button button-dark col col-30 ion-camera" ng-click="getPic()">Camera</button>
<img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" style="text-align: center">
```

**I need help for:** Camera should record photos and videos. It's taking right now only photos.
[PICTURE: The Videocamera Button is not clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDmru.jpg)

Comment: I guess you may have to use cordova media plugin in that case as camera plugin supports taking pictures and selecting pictures from video section. Someone correct me if i m wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't take a look at the code of this app yet (it's an **Ionic 2** App and it only records videos) but you can take a look at the plugins used there and how they work (working on nexus 7 2013).

https://github.com/rossmartin/video-editor-ionic2

These are the required plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-camera 
cordova-plugin-device 
cordova-plugin-media-capture 
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard.git 
cordova-plugin-statusbar 
cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog 
cordova-plugin-instagram-assets-picker 
cordova-plugin-video-editor
```